# How to remove custom stem removing y from end of word?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Are there any out-of-the-box stemming algorithms which remove y from the ends of words? If not how is making funky = funk generally dealt with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd stick to `lovins` English [stem filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/analysis-stemmer-tokenfilter.html). You can set-up your mapping via following setting:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/my_test_01 -d '
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer" : {
        "my_analyzer" : {
          "tokenizer" : "standard",
          "filter" : ["standard", "lowercase", "my_stemmer"]
        }
      },
      "filter" : {
        "my_stemmer" : {
          "type" : "stemmer",
          "name" : "lovins"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "stem": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

I've tested it and it does good job for:

- `funky` -> `funk`
- `funny` -> `fun`
- `generally` -> `general`
- `prohibitively` -> `prohibit`
- `singlehandedly` -> `singlehanded`
- `nifty` -> `nift`